# What are the cases which can cause data conflict at the row level in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

Cassandra has one single master copy for each row and it is being replicated on multiple nodes as per cluster configuration. I want to understand the cases which can cause data conflict at the row level especially when each row has only one master copy. Some examples would be helpful.

Comment: there is no master-replica distinction in terms of writing the row. The primary key is hashed to determine the node with primary responsibility, then the data is sent out simultaneously to all the nodes. depending on the consistency level, the response is sent to the client after 1, quorum, or all nodes have replied.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of master copy in Cassandra. Each row is hashed into a token based on your primary key and hashing algorithm (random or mumur3) and the node which is responsible for the token gets the first copy of data. Depending on your **Replication Factor** (number of copies), other nodes in the ring get the other copies.

If you set the **RF** to 1, the node containing that data may go down (corrupt) and you will not be able to retrieve that data. As a best practice, you should start with **RF=3** in production and change the **RF** based on your needs moving forward. RF of 1 is ok for testing purposes.

Hope that helps!